# Is native app vulnerable to FREAK attack? If yes, how to detect it as a user?

Tags: tls, known-vulnerabilities, library

When I research about FREAK attack, most of them explain about the server and *browser* vulnerability, but how about native apps (e.g. Windows executable program, mobile apps)?

From [Mark's answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/83155/59741)  on [Can someone explain, in simple terms, how the FREAK attack on browsers works?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83150/can-someone-explain-in-simple-terms-how-the-freak-attack-on-browsers-works),

> As far as I can tell, the "FREAK" vulnerability affects the SChannel library (Internet Explorer and related Windows browsers), Apple's SSL library (Safari and other MacOSX/IOS browsers), and OpenSSL (most Android browsers and a scattering of Linux browsers). The NSS library (Firefox and Chrome) does not appear to be affected.

it seems that it's related to the TLS libraries they are using. Is it also the same for native apps?

If it is, then *as a user*, how can we detect that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's the same for native apps.

On Windows, you can simply assume that the application is using SChannel and be right 99% of the time; the same for MacOSX/iOS and Secure Transport.  On Linux, you can run `ldd /path/to/program/binary` and inspect the output for either `libgnutls` (GnuTLS) or `libssl` (OpenSSL/LibreSSL).  I don't know how you'd figure it out for Android.